# Firebase - Google Login - Cannot get currentUser in incognito/new browser - even though I am using onAuthStateChanged handler

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am getting really inconsistent results while using Firebase google authentication. It's a really simple implementation as you can see below. From the firebase documentation, it seems like this is all I really have to do. I AM using the `onAuthStateChanged` observer as recommended by Google.

However, here's what's happening. I consistently get the logged in user in my normal Chrome browser. However, in incognito, or in another browser, like Safari, it ALWAYS redirects back to the login page, and the user is null. If I look in `auth`, the `currentUser` is null. But it almost always works in my normal chrome browser. Is there some weird caching thing at play here? Any guidance will be much appreciated.

- Firebase Version: 9.23.0
- React Version: 17.0.2

App.js

```
import { auth, login, logout, onAuthStateChanged } from "../tools/firebase";

function App() {
  const [userState, setUserState] = useState({});

  useEffect(() => {
    const unsubscribe = onAuthStateChanged(auth, (user) => {
      if (user) {
        console.log({ user });
        setUserState({ user });
      } else {
        console.log("User is null");
      }
    });

    return function () {
      unsubscribe();
    };
  }, [userState.user]);

  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={login}>Google Login</button>
      <button onClick={logout}>Google Logout</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

firebase.js

```
import {
  getAuth,
  signInWithRedirect,
  GoogleAuthProvider,
  onAuthStateChanged,
} from "firebase/auth";

const provider = new GoogleAuthProvider();
const auth = getAuth();
function login() {
  signInWithRedirect(auth, provider);
}

function logout() {
  auth.signOut();
}

export { login, logout, auth, onAuthStateChanged };
```

Here's a gif to demo the issue. You will notice that I get the user object in normal mode, but I always get "User is null" in incognito
[image: User null in Incognito]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't get any responses here. While i still don't understand why i get inconsistent results using the above code.

But, I was able to solve the problem using the `reactfire` library. For those that are experiencing similar difficulties, seems like that library is pretty handy.

They have a great example of an auth implementation here:
https://github.com/FirebaseExtended/reactfire/blob/main/example/withoutSuspense/Auth.tsx